# Trying to filter through a list: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of null"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, frontend, filtering

I'm trying to filter through a list, but keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of null". I can't seem to figure out why locations.Name would be null. I purposely use `this.locations = initializeLocations()` to prevent it. The data is there and my list gets generated well (with ngFor).

Typescript

```js
//Imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-locaties',
  templateUrl: './locaties.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./locaties.component.css'],
})
export class LocatiesComponent implements OnInit {
  // the full list
  masterLocations: any = [];
  locations: any = [];
  user;

  constructor(
    private toolbarTitle: ToolbarTitleService,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    private syncService: SyncServiceService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.toolbarTitle.setToolbarTitle('Locaties');
    this.user = await this.userService.getUser();
    // Haalt alle shops van de gebruiker op en zet ze in locations
    await this.initializeLocations();
  }

  async initializeLocations() {
    this.masterLocations = await this.syncService.getShops(this.user);

    if (this.locations.length === 0) {
      this.locations = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.masterLocations));
    }
  }

  // Popover
  async presentPopover(ev: any, Contact: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverComponent,
      componentProps: {
        phones: Contact.Phones[0].Number,
        email: Contact.Email,
        street: Contact.Addresses[0].Street1,
        city: Contact.Addresses[0].City,
      },
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }

  filterList(ev: any) {
    const val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.masterLocations));

      this.locations = clone.filter((item) => {
        return item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
    } else {
      this.locations = this.masterLocations;
    }
  }

  selectVal(val) {
    alert('you have selected = ' + val);
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<ion-content fullscreen>
  <!-- Searchbar with a placeholder -->

  <!-- (ionChange)="ionChange($event)" -->
  <ion-searchbar
    debounce="1000"
    (ionInput)="filterList($event)"
    placeholder="Zoek een locatie"
  ></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <!-- locatie cards -->
      <ion-col class="row1" size="11">
        <ion-list lines="none">
          <ion-item
            (click)="selectVal(location.Name)"
            *ngFor="let location of locations"
          >
            <ion-card class="locatieCard">
              <ion-item>
                <img
                  class="locatieImg"
                  src="assets/spar_img.jpg"
                  slot="start"
                />
                <ion-grid>
                  <ion-row>
                    <ion-card-subtitle>{{ location.Name }}</ion-card-subtitle>
                  </ion-row>
                  <ion-row>
                    <ion-button
                      size="small"
                      fill="clear"
                      (click)="presentPopover($event, location.Contact)"
                    >
                      Meer info
                    </ion-button>
                  </ion-row>
                </ion-grid>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col class="row2" size="1"> ion col 2 </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

This is what `getShops()` in `initializeLocations()` returns:
[image: getSgops return]

this is the code:

```js
  getShops(user: any) {
    const selector = {
      _id: { $in: user.Shops },
    };
    return this.dbService.localDB
      .find({
        selector,
      })
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log('SHOPS: ', result.docs);
        return result.docs;
      });
  }
```

Error message
[image]

Comment: @MatthewProSkils I’ll update with the html

Comment: Can you please show the entire error message including the stacktrace? Just to get a grip of where the error might derrive from.

Comment: @Lynx242 Done so now. Added an image at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my assumption is, that you mix asynchronity with synchronity. The first thing you do in your `filterList()` method is to call `this.initializeLocations();`. Which triggers

```
this.locations = await this.syncService.getShops(this.user);
```

Although you work with `await` here, it is still an async operation from the view of `filterList()`. It won't wait for this operation to finish.

So while this call is being processed you work a second time with `this.locations` while you try to filter it. And I reckon that the async process from above cleared the array already and waits for the new value to put it in.

Remove

```
this.initializeLocations();
```

from your filter-method. This will do the trick.

Now you have to care for the list to be used as database and not be overwritten. So what we do now is, to bring in a list with `masterLocations`.

```
export class LocatiesComponent implements OnInit {
    // the full list
    masterLocations: any = [];

    // the filtered list
    locations: any = [];

    // the user
    user;
```

Get the master list here

```
async initializeLocations() {
    this.masterLocations = await this.syncService.getShops(this.user);
}
```

And the filtered list here. With `JSON.pare(JSON.stringify())` we generate a clone of the entire list.

```
filterList(ev: any) {
    const val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.masterLocations));
 
        this.locations = clone.filter((item) => {
           return item.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
    } 
     else {
          this.locations = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.masterLocations));
    }

}
```

Comment: Alright, removing `this.initializeLocations();` finally makes it filter! But my list won't return to normal. After clearing the searchbar the stores don't come back..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot 1 line of code in `initializeLocations()`. I just added it.

Comment: Adding `if (this.locations.length === 0) {
       this.locations = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.masterLocations));
    }` to `initializeLocations()` makes it not filter anymore. 
EDIT:it finally works sort of. I'm only having trouble with getting the full list back after clearing the searchbar.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then please remove it. I thought you wanted to show the full list directly at start and filter afterwards. My bad. I just removed it from my answer.

Comment: No, that's actually what I do want. Have the full list when the page is loaded and filtering only when typing in the searchbar. The default should be having the full list